# $event.target.value won't work on click event

Tags: angular, html, web, angular5

I'm trying to pass the value of the clicked element into a function to change data dynamically on the page. My code looks somewhat like this:

```
<li value={{some value}} (click)="someFunction($event.target.value,someargument)">
```

Comment: Try passing `event` only in function.

Comment: Code is working fine you can see here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzcsrm?file=app/app.component.html, there might be error somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to **currentTarget** and it works fine

```
<li value={{someValue}} (click)="someFunction($event.currentTarget.value, someargument)">
```

in your *.ts file

```
someFunction(value, someargument){
  // will print someValue
  console.log(value);
}
```